# How do I move Power BI parameters to another page?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a Power BI report with a dozen parameters slicers in it. Now I want my parameters and my charts/tables to be on separate pages. Copying and pasting the visuals onto another page somehow unlink it from the parameters.

How can I put my existing visuals and parameter slicers on separate pages?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with 'parameter' because any parameter created with either PowerQuery or DAX is totally independent from the report pages.

Comment: I meant the ["What-if"  parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if).